# Likelihood ration Algebraic issue

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, statistics, summation, logarithms

I have got the following likelihood:

$$l(p) = C + xlog(p) + (n-x)log(1-p)$$

I have got that $\theta_0 = 1/3$  and  $\theta_1 = 1/2$

All I need to do is find the correct value of the log likelihood in its simplest terms. the problem is that I am coming to realize really fast that my algebra is pretty bad! Here is what i have got to so far:

$$l(1/2) = C + xlog(1/2) + (n-x)log(1/2)$$
$$l(1/3) = C + xlog(1/3) + (n-x)log(2/3)$$
$$log(LR) = [C + xlog(1/2) + (n-x)log(1/2)] - [C + xlog(1/3) + (n-x)log(2/3)]$$
$$log(LR) = C + xlog(1/2) + (n-x)log(1/2) - C - xlog(1/3) - (n-x)log(2/3)$$
$$log(LR) = xlog(1/2) + (n-x)log(1/2)  - xlog(1/3) - (n-x)log(2/3)$$
$$log(LR) = x(log(1/2)- log(1/3)) + (n-x)(log(1/2) - log(2/3))$$
$$log(LR) = x(log(3/2)) + (n-x)(log(3/4))$$
$$log(LR) = x(log(3)-log(2)) + (n-x)(log(3)-log(4))$$

This expression can be simplified further as pert my text book multiple choice of answers but my algebraic brain has had a total meltdown!
Please help!

Comment: Maybe they want you to write it as $x \log \frac{3}{2} - x \log \frac{3}{4}  + n \log \frac{3}{4}= x \log 2 + n \log \frac{3}{4}$?

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for $\log$ using `\log`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use '\operatorname{name}'.

Comment: @angryavian that makes perfect sense now! I did't know that i can express $(n-x)\log\frac{3}{4}$ as $n\log\frac{3}{4}-x\log\frac{3}{4}$
Please write it as an answer so that i can mark it as correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Copy of comment):

Maybe they want you to write it as
$$x \log \frac{3}{2} - x \log \frac{3}{4} + n \log \frac{3}{4} = x \log 2 + n \log \frac{3}{4}$$